# Figuring out which interfaces a class has implemented in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

I am having some issues to design various relations with classes and interfaces since TypeScript does not allow certain typecasts as C# would.

My current hierarchy is the following:

```
interface IComponent {}
interface IBehaviour1 {}
interface IBehaviour2 {}
class Component implements IComponent, IBehaviour1 {}
class SpecializedComponent extends Component implements IBehaviour2 {}
```

In another class I am storing a `Set<IComponent>` collection where I register multiple `Component` and `SpecializedComponent` objects. However in one function I need to iterate over all of them and call the `IBehaviour1` specific method if present and the `IBehaviour2` specific method if present as well.

Since I am calling this method a lot I decided to create to sets `Set<IBehaviour1>` and `Set<IBehaviour2>` - each time I call `addComponent` I would then categorize the new component appropriately.

In C# this would look like this:

```
void AddComponent(IComponent component)
{
    if (component is IBehaviour1)
        behaviour1Components.Add((IBehaviour1)component);
    if (component is IBehaviour2)
        behaviour2Components.Add((IBehaviour2)component);
}
```

Unfortunately TypeScript doesn't allow the specific typecheck/comparison as shown above since `IBehaviour1` and `IBehaviour2` aren't compatible with `IComponent`. Furthermore both sets aren't disjoint. I am curious how I should store all components such that I can call all behaviour methods if present.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, but did you try to use a generic setup like `void Add component<T extends IComponent>(component: T)` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Typescript interfaces are just a compile time contruct. What matters is if the methods/fields you need to use actually exists on the object at runtime, and that is the test you should perform. To make things more syntactically pleasing, you can use a type-guard to help with type inference:

```
interface IComponent { }
interface IBehaviour1 {
  behaviour1Method(): void
}
interface IBehaviour2 {
  behaviour2Method(): void
}
class Component implements IComponent, IBehaviour1 {
  behaviour1Method(): void { }
}
class SpecializedComponent extends Component implements IBehaviour2 {
  behaviour2Method(): void { }
}

function isIBehaviour1(a: any): a is IBehaviour1 {
  return (a as IBehaviour1).behaviour1Method != null;
}
function isIBehaviour2(a: any): a is IBehaviour2 {
  return (a as IBehaviour2).behaviour2Method != null;
}

class Usage {
  behaviour1Components: IBehaviour1[] = []
  behaviour2Components: IBehaviour2[] = []
  addComponent(component: IComponent): void {
    if (isIBehaviour1(component)) {
      this.behaviour1Components.push(component);
    }
    if (isIBehaviour2(component)) {
      this.behaviour2Components.push(component);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion works as intended, thank you very much. I figured out a minor change to the type guard functions: `function isIBehaviour1<T extends IComponent>(a: T): a is T & IBehaviour1 { return ((a as IComponent) as IBehaviour1).behaviour1Method !== undefined; }` - Is there any particular difference?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic that version should work just as well, and it keep the source type as well if you need it

Comment: I noticed a minor issue with my version (which only works with an empty `IComponent` as in your sample) - since my `IComponent` has a `componentFunction()` my version has an error as `IComponent` cannot be converted to either `IBehaviour1` or `IBehaviour2`. In the end I have to use yours.

Comment: you can cast to `any` instead of `IComponent` the result can stay the same, `return ((a as any) as IBehaviour1).behaviour1Method !== undefined`